# insert data to database mysql from netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans, insert

I have stack in my register form. I don't get it where the error
this is my connection:

```
package login;

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.*;

public class register extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public PreparedStatement pst;
public Connection cn;
public Statement st;

public register() {
    initComponents();
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tugas?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","");
        st=cn.createStatement();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Connected");
    }
}
```

I have buttonclick to save or insert to database, but it's failed or error:

```
private void btnsumbitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try {
        String sql = "INSERT INTO `pasien`(`Username`, `Password`, `Nama_Depan`, "
                + "`Nama_Belakang`, `Tanggal_Lahir`, `Alamat`, `No_Telp`, `Jenis_Kelamin`) "
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        pst = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1, user.getText());
        pst.setString(2, String.valueOf(pass.getPassword()));
        pst.setString(3, nmdepan.getText());
        pst.setString(4, nmblkg.getText());
        pst.setString(5, ((JTextField)txt_Date.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        pst.setString(6, alamat.getText());
        pst.setString(7, telp.getText());
        pst.setString(8, kelamin.getSelectedItem().toString());
        pst.execute();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Register Berhasil");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Terjadi Kesalahan");
    }
}
```

This code can execute but can't insert to database or failed.

Comment: don't output a fixed (useless) error message on failure. mysql can/will tell you what went wrong. the exception itself should contain the error code/text from mysql...

Comment: it's my data of database
Username : varchar(20), Password : varchar(20), Nama_Depan : varchar(20), Nama_Belakang : varchar(20), Tanggal_Lahir : date, Alamat : varchar(100), No_Telp : varchar(15), Jenis_Kelamin : varchar(10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give us some more information :

- sql table variables
- output error

Look the type of your variables 
or use this code to catch better the errror

```
try {
     //You code there
}
catch (SQLException e) {
  while (e != null) {
      System.out.println("\n Message: " + e.getMessage());
      System.out.println("\n SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
      System.out.println("\n ErrorCode: " + e.getErrorCode());
      e = e.getNextException();
  }
}
```

Comment: i put that code but cant compile/error so it's my type data in database
Username : varchar(20), Password : varchar(20), Nama_Depan : varchar(20), Nama_Belakang : varchar(20), Tanggal_Lahir : date, Alamat : varchar(100), No_Telp : varchar(15), Jenis_Kelamin : varchar(10)